# ios MKMapView in grey?

Tags: ios, styles, mkmapview

I recently saw an example of Google maps in grey on a website (Can't remember where). I mean grey in the sense that the streets, parks etc are drawn just in a grey tone not in green yellow and so on.

Now, in my iPhone app I would like to tell a MKMapView object to draw the maps in grey tones. But I cannot find anything about that in the documentation.

Therefore I'm wondering if this is possible in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have been seeing Styled Maps, which is a feature of the v3 javascript api, but not of iOS https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

You may be able to rig something up with a layer over your map view that changes the color of what ever is underneath it and doesn't interfere with touch events, but depending on what your map is for it might be easier to render your own tiles.